# How to add checkbox selected items in a array - Angular

Tags: angular

I have checkbox column in mat-table to select all or some items.
I am getting the selected ids but struggling to put the selected userIDs in an array of object.
How can I add the selected items in an array named userIDs?

The Ts file:

```
 userIDs: any[];
 sendRegretMail() {
  this.selection.selected.forEach(s => console.log(s.id));
  }
```

This is the body of my post request:[image]

Answer (score 2):

**For your current solution**

```
userIDs: any[];
sendRegretMail() {
  this.selection.selected.forEach(s => {
    console.log(s.id);
    userIDs.push({"id": s.id}); // Just push object of id with define array
  });
}
```

**Another Solution**

```
this.userIDs = this.selection.selected.map(o => ({id: o.id}));
```

Comment: 2nd one is okay but for 1st solution, i need to initiate userIDs like userIDs = [ ]; otherwise push() shows undefined.
Thnx for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
userIDs = this.selection.selected.map(s => ({id: s.id}));
```